# Does the fact that random.sample(seq, 1)[0] === random.choice(seq) mean that both functions should have the same precondition on seq?

Tags: python, api-design, python-3.x

I've read https://bugs.python.org/issue33098, which is about the following behavior of Python 3

```
a = {'1': 42, '2': 84}  # keys are str on purpose, c.f. the issue

import random
random.choice(a.keys())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/nix/store/.../lib/python3.7/random.py", line 262, in choice
    return seq[i]
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing
```

I've discovered that this functionally equivalent call succeeds just fine

```
random.sample(a.keys(), 1)[0]
'1'
```

Given the justification on the issue, is there any deeper principled reason why the two functions should behave differently, are there practical considerations for making `sample()` more flexible in its arguments, or is it all just an implementation accident?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support for `random.sample(a.keys(), 1)[0]` is an implementation accident and can break down in future Python3 versions.
There is good reason to recommend that neither `choice()` nor `sample()` supports a dictionary or a 'dict_keys' object as an argument. As Tim Peters say:

> The dict type doesn't support efficient random choice (neither do sets, by the way), and it's been repeatedly decided that it would do a disservice to users to hide that.

This answer is for both `choice()` and `sample()`! If speed matter, don't use standard dictionary!

If you really don't care about speed, at least, you should try a better approach (memory-free + save half-time in average):

```
import random, itertools

def randkey(dic):
    pos = random.randrange(0, len(dic))
    res, = itertools.islice(dic, pos, pos + 1)
    return res

randkey({"a": 1, "b": 1, "c": 1})
'b'
```

If I don't convince you:

---

Due to implementation detail:

```
random.sample(a.keys(), 1)[0]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
random.sample(tuple(a.keys()), 1)[0]
```

So the `.keys()` call is pointless and should be replaced by a `list()` or `tuple()` call:

```
random.sample(list(a), 1)[0]
```

The `sample()` function warn you when you try to use the dictionary directly as parameter:

```
random.sample({}, 1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 317, in sample
    raise TypeError("Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).")
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d).
```

---

Due to implementation detail, `choice()` function expect a object that support `__len__` and `__getitem__` methods:

```
class MyDuckTypingObject:
    def __len__(self):
        return 1000000
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return key

random.choice(MyDuckTypingObject())
212426
```

But 'dict_keys' object only support `__len__`:

```
{}.keys().__len__
<method-wrapper '__len__' of dict object at 0x7fecf0820630>
{"a": "a"}.keys().__len__()
1
{}.keys().__getitem__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict_keys' object has no attribute '__getitem__
```

Again, a solution is to call `list()` or `tuple()` instead of `.keys()`:

```
random.choice(list(a))
```